# How do I change the scaling options in AMD Catalyst Control Center?

Tags: amd-radeon, scaling, overscan

I've just switched out my old GTX 470 for a new ASUS Radeon R9 280X and now when I choose the resolution 1920 x 1080 it doesn't fit my 1920 x 1080 monitor. It just doesn't fill up the whole screen and leaves black bars around the image. I read that this can be because of the scaling options in AMD Catalyst Control Center, so I checked it out and noticed that my scaling-options are locked. I can't lower or raise the overscan to make the image fill out the whole monitor. Does anyone know what is causing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You removed the Nvidia drivers before you attempted to install the AMD drivers right? What operating system?  What driver release are you using?  Update your question otherwise I can't help.

Comment: Good question. Hope I don't run into this when I upgrade :X